# no value for a JSON key

Tags: android, json

i'm trying to parse this json

```
    {
      "data": [
    {  "name": "4th Floor",
          "is_broken": true,
          "is_repaired": false,
          "is_ok": false,
          "asset_parent": {
            "name": "Buni Building",
            "is_broken": true,
            "is_repaired": false,
            "is_ok": false
          }
        }
      ]
}
```

with this code

```
 class daftarAset extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Sedang menampilkan...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String link_url = "https://example.com/api/assets";
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String json = sh.makeServiceCall(link_url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + json);
            if (json != null) {
                try {
                   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject ar = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    String aset = ar.getString("name");

                    JSONObject parent = ar.getJSONObject("asset_parent");
                    String nama = parent.getString("name");
                    HashMap map = new HashMap();
                    map.put(in_aset, aset);
                    map.put(in_ruang, nama);
                    data_map.add(map);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.baik_list);
                    adapter = new AssetsAdapter(getActivity(), data_map);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list);

                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

and it says error that **no value for data**. i dont know why the data said no value where i already call it before with JSONArray. it must be nothing to do with the listview where i have to put the value. 
please help why it says has no value for data but it actualy has

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting error because **you aren't passing the json string to your json object**.

it should be

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

instead of

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(); //json is missing here
```

Comment: i've got this error after that Value null at asset_parent of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject. do you know why it cannot be converted?

Comment: can you email the project so that i can look into it

Comment: i think the problem is when i call the 'asset_parent' key from json which is alse JSONObject. i saw tutorial here (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) and i think it should be right. but why it cannot be converted

Comment: can i have your email?